# Extracting data from Cursor in onLoadFinished for Loader Manager

Tags: android, cursor, android-loadermanager

I have the lines of code in onLoadFinished for my Loader Manager callback in a fragment. The problem with the code is that the favoriteMovies is needed to  be displayed in the ArrayAdapter so fo what ever reason, it is zero while the log statement show that the cursor or data is not empty.

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Loader Manager Loading Finished: " + data.getCount());
    if (data != null && data.getCount() > 0) {
            while (data.moveToNext()) {
                favouriteMovies.add(
                        new Movie(
                                data.getString(2),
                                data.getString(3),
                                data.getString(4),
                                data.getInt(1),
                                data.getString(5),
                                data.getDouble(6),
                                data.getDouble(7)
                        ));

        }
        setMovies(favouriteMovies);
        hideLoadingProgress();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    } else {
        showEmptyView(EMPTY_VIEW_TYPE_LOCAL);
        hideLoadingProgress();
    }

}
```

How can i write this code so that it actually waits fro the while statement to finish before calling the setMovies() method. When i minimize my app to the background and restore it, the movies are diaplayed, but it does not work in the first time it is called.

Comment: `"The problem with the code is that the favoriteMovies is needed to be displayed in the ArrayAdapter"`, yes indeed, this is a problem, dont use `ArrayAdapter` when dealing with `Cursor` based data, use `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead (or any other `CursorAdapter`)

Comment: You are right, but SimpleCursorAdapter will not serve as part of the data is gotten from the server as a json using retrofit which is mapped to a model so i have two data sources.

Comment: use `MatrixCursor` then, most likely in combination with `MergeCursor`

Comment: I will check that out. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial i simple have to check the cursor to know if it is the last index and then call my other function as shown below.

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Loader Manager Loading Finished: " + data.getCount());
    favouriteMovies.clear();
    if (data != null && data.getCount() > 0) {
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            favouriteMovies.add(
                    new Movie(
                            data.getString(2),
                            data.getString(3),
                            data.getString(4),
                            data.getInt(1),
                            data.getString(5),
                            data.getDouble(6),
                            data.getDouble(7)
                    ));
            if (data.isLast()) {
                setMovies(favouriteMovies);
                hideLoadingProgress();
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }


    } else {
        showEmptyView(EMPTY_VIEW_TYPE_LOCAL);
        hideLoadingProgress();
    }

}
```